# Function to show next 4 li with click and so on until the end of li

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

since the code`$ ('. p> li: gt (2)')` show only the first 2, I want to change my function to show with a click next 4 li (4,5 and 6), then with the click another click show the next 4 (7,8,9 and 10).

For now I've created a function to show everything.
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/462125/

here is html:

```
<div class="show-4">
<ul class="p">
        <li class="f">1</li>
        <li class="f">2</li>
        <li class="f">3</li>
        <li class="f">4</li>
        <li class="f">5</li>
        <li class="f">6</li>
        <li class="f">7</li>
        <li class="f">8</li>
        <li class="f">9</li>
        <li class="f">10</li>
        <button id="sum" class="btn-default btn" style="">show</button>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and jquery code:

```
 $('.p >li:gt(2)').hide();
        $("#sum").click(function () {
            $('.f').siblings('li').show();
            $("#sum").hide();
        });
```

Comment: Presently not clear what you're asking...

Comment: @Utkanos you know jquery? just see the jquery code and you will see what iam asking

Comment: I know jQuery, but I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Utkanos I'm asking how do I change my jquery function to show with the next click 4 li and so on until the end of the list

Comment: And it's that sentence, "to show with the next click 4 li and so on until the end of the list" that I don't understand. I appreciate English isn't your first language, but you may find more people can help if you can rework that sentence.

Comment: @A.Dubosky https://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: @ChrisSatchell I already check slice, but slice hides the ones above.

Comment: @Utkanos I changed the question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying the following:

`$('.f').siblings('li:hidden').slice(0,4).show();`

This will select all hidden siblings, take the first four and set their visibility.

Comment: is there any option to remove the button when it reaches the end?

Comment: You could use a conditional and check whether there are still any hidden elements left to display